# Jupyter labelling z-axis gives nameerror

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have the following block of code to produce a 3D plot of sets of data:

```
figure(figsize=(20, 15))
ax = gca(projection="3d")
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
xlabel("x")
ylabel("y")
zlabel("z")
show()
```

However, an error is made when labelling the z-axis:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-987e9d2dec12> in <module>()
      4 xlabel("x")
      5 ylabel("y")
----> 6 zlabel("z")
      7 show()

NameError: name 'zlabel' is not defined
```

I defined the z-axis using the following code earlier:

```
def z(x, y):

    b = 0.5**(x**2+y**2)
    return sin(b)

Z_data = z(X, Y)
```

I can't see what the problem appears to be. What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

As I am calling `ax  = gca()` it seemed appropriate to use the `ax` method.

Hence, discovering on google that `ax.set_zlabel('z')` also managed to do the job gave me the solution I needed.